# Why does SDL window immediately close?

Tags: c++, sdl

This is my C++ file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "window.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
     std::cout << "Something went wrong" << std::endl;
}
  else { 
   SDL_CreateWindow("Neptune's Limit", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1024, 768, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it flashes up for a half a second and then immediately closes. I have looked at the other posts about this, but the answer to them was about `SDL_EVENT`. I do not have that anywhere in my program.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Your window closes because your program ends. If you don't want it to end you'll need to do something to stop that. Take a look at the SDL sample programs and tutorials.

Comment: I prevented the program from ending but got the same result. I declared char a; and used std::cin >> a; but the window did the same thing

Comment: Add an event loop, something like what's described in this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424816/sdl-window-does-not-show/41044089#41044089

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, thank you. Been a long day.

Comment: Thanks so much @RetiredNinja

Answer (score 5):

After create `SDL` window, use `while` loop for maintain `SDL` window.
I learn basic `SDL` functions with this [tutorial](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/index.php)

**SIMPLE EXAMPLE**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

   if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0) {
     std::cout << "Something went wrong" << std::endl;
   } else { 
     SDL_CreateWindow("Neptune's Limit", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1024, 768, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
     while( true ) {
       // SDL RUNNING
       // Poll Event Code Maybe here!
     }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Maybe this code doesn't exit because there's no `exit-SDL` code.

For exit program, add `SDL`_Event:

> `SDL POLL EVENT EX)`

```
SDL_Event e;
while(true) { // SDL loop
  while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) != 0 ) {
    if( event.type == SDL_QUIT ) {
      // Ctrl + C in console !
    }
  } // end of handling event.
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your answer and the hint for a tutorial. In SO, it is common to post your code directly, so maybe you could add the `while` loop to the code given in the question?

Comment: thank you for your advice. I add simple code for tutorial!!