# How to create a window with SDL2 on MacOS

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I'm trying to create a window with SDL2. I don't get any error while compiling, but I also don't get any window at runtime.

Here's my code (without error checking for readability).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(void)
{
    SDL_Window      *win = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer    *ren = NULL;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(320, 640, 0, &win, &ren);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);

    SDL_Delay(3000);

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();

    return (0);
}
```

I also tried [this](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow) code sample from the wiki, same issue.

**Compilation**

`clang -F /Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2 main.c`

I'm working on MacOS Big Sur. I installed the SDL2 from the `.dmg` file downloaded on [their website](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) (runtime binaries / Mac OS X), and placed into the `/Library/Frameworks` folder

Is that a compatibility issue? How can I fix it?

**EDIT**

I also tried to install the SDL following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@edkins.sarah/set-up-sdl2-on-your-mac-without-xcode-6b0c33b723f7), still same issue.

Comment: Your code works for me - a black window for 3 seconds spawned.

Comment: That's why I think there's a compatibility issue with this version of the SDL2 and macOS BigSur, I don't get any window, I tried with several different codes...

Comment: Add `SDL_PollEvent` and an event loop. You'll need it anyway to process input, and I heard on some platforms windows don't show up otherwise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an event loop to get the window -

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(void)
{
    SDL_Window      *win = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer    *ren = NULL;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(320, 640, 0, &win, &ren);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(ren, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    bool quit = false;

            //Event handler
            SDL_Event e;

            //While application is running
            while( !quit )
            {
                //Handle events on queue
                while( SDL_PollEvent( &e ) != 0 ) // poll for event
                {
                    //User requests quit
                    if( e.type == SDL_QUIT ) // unless player manually quits
                    {
                        quit = true;
                    }
                }
            }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I'll definitely try it this afternoon, but isnt it supposed to print the window even without event loop? The documentation says it has to work without.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. We need to have a core game loop otherwise the window gets destroyed after the 3s delay.

Comment: But that's what I actually want, I don't want the window to stay open after those 3 secs, I just want it to appear at least once

Comment: Anyway I tried and you're right, I don't understand why but it works

Comment: It's a platform specific issue I guess. Your code works on windows, on mac os you need to have a game loop. If you want it to close after 3 seconds delay, you can add a break after SDL_Delay(3000) in outer while loop.

Comment: you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424816/sdl-window-does-not-show for more info